# Magento2 Compile command ends at Repositories code generation 1/7

Tags: magento2, composer, repository

- Magento v2.1.7 CE
- PHP 7.0
- Permissions double checked

When I run compile command through cli, it ends at step 2 as seen in the image below.

[image]

I found that it might be due to a wrong auth.json in composer settings which is used for magento repo. I could not find any auth.json file though, the composer folder was present in the parent directory as `.composer` but it had only one folder `cache`.

It used to work well as this is not a fresh installation. Any clues or guidance?

Comment: Try running 'php bin/magento -vvv setup:di:compile' for more verbosity while the command is running. Hopefully that provides some additional insight into what's happening.

Comment: @Pmclain I tried that. Same output on console

Comment: Any solution? I face the same...