# magento 2.2.1 setup:di:compile not finished / Fails

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

I did an upgrade from Magento 2.1.10 to 2.2.1, after some known issues the site is up again.

When I run a command setup:di:compile the compilation seems to be broken (see picture below). Also the var/di folder is empty.

How can I tackle this problem, or is DI not necessary any more in Magento 2.2?

[image: I dids]

Comment: Hi @Jilco Tigchelaar Could you Please put error here so we can approach some solution ?

Comment: Only error i see is in system.log - main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 60000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes

Comment: seems to be the same as https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187076/magento2-compile-command-ends-at-repositories-code-generation-1-7

Comment: And this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199594/magento-2-compile-command-fail-but-no-errors

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you have an error in one of your modules, would suggest to display error using **/app/bootstrap.php**

> ini_set('display_errors', 1);